# System.Argument out of exception:Specified argument was out of range of valid value

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, client-server, tcp

After several fixes, I am still having a nasty error. I debug and run my server using Developer Command Prompt for `VS2013` and run client using VS 2013.

Firstly I run my server without any issues, but when I start the client, put data in a `textbox` there  and click send problem arises.

This is the code on server side which directs the issue.

```
IPAddress ipaddr=IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(ipaddr,8002);

int requestCount = 0;

TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);

serverSocket.Start();

Console.WriteLine(" >> Server Started");

clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

Console.WriteLine(" >> Accept connection from client");

requestCount = 0;

while ((true))
{
    try
    {
        requestCount = requestCount + 1;

        NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
        //issue stems out of here although i changed bytes size and tried too
        networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);

        string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
        dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));

        Console.WriteLine(" >> Data from client - " + dataFromClient);

        string serverResponse = "Last Message from client" + dataFromClient;

        Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);

        networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
        networkStream.Flush();

        Console.WriteLine(" >> " + serverResponse);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}

clientSocket.Close();
serverSocket.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(" >> exit");
Console.ReadLine();
```

**EDIT :** After a suggestion, I changed :

```
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);`
```

to

```
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length);
```

resulted in the screen shot given but with no data from client received.

[image: Screenshot]

Error (from Command Prompt):-

> Parameter name:size at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(byte[] buffer,int offset,int size)
>
> at Console.Application1.Prog.Main():
>   System Argument Out of Exception:Specified Argument was out of range of valid value.

What actually are they calling `valid value`.

PS. Apology if the code here I provided is too long but its the need

Comment: What is the value of `(int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize)`?

Comment: From client side i was sending `byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox2.Text + "$");

            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);`

Comment: So, a 'hey' was sent from textbox and a 10025 was allocated on server side to rceieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify receiveBuffer size as third parameter, not `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize`

`networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length);`

OR

create a buffer with clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;

```
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

Here is example from microsoft:

```
while(true) 
      {
        Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

        // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
        // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();            
        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

        data = null;

        // Get a stream object for reading and writing
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        int i;

        // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
        while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0) 
        {   
          // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
          data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
          Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

          // Process the data sent by the client.
          data = data.ToUpper();

          byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

          // Send back a response.
          stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
          Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);            
        }

        // Shutdown and end connection
        client.Close();
      }
```

Comment: Your both suggestions i tried and resulted in errorless but no-output

Answer (score 0):

This question was so long ago but it may be useful for other people. I want to suggest you to do the same thing on the client side. You should change the receive part of client code as below;

```
byte[] inStream = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];

serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
```